predict in R with non-matching formula names
I just ran into a mystery:
> df <- data.frame( x <- rnorm(N), y <- rnorm(N), z <- rnorm(N) )
> formula <- y ~ x + z
> names(df)
[1] "x....rnorm.N." "y....rnorm.N." "z....rnorm.N."

my formula names obviously don't match my variable names (my bug).  alas, this works, but shouldn't have:
> coef( mylm <- lm( formula, data=df ) )
(Intercept)           x           z 
    0.18945     0.08351     0.08023 

lateron, this creates trouble for me.
> predict( mylm, newdata= df[1,] )
...gives a warning and 30 rows of observations, not 1...

> names(df) <- c("x","y","z")
> predict( mylm, newdata= df[1,] )
    1 
0.139 

so, at a minimum, I need to figure out how to check that my formula corresponds to variables that actually exist in my data frame.  How?  (I am trying to write a simple function that creates recursive regression residuals to doublecheck theone from strucchange.)

Side-note - do data.frame(x = rnorm(N)) with = to avoid getting the non-matching names. You don't use <- inside a function call typically.

The reason this works (I think) is because somewhere internal we do eval(predvars, data) where predvars is an expression list(x,y,z) and data is a data frame; data frame lookup appears to do partial matching in this case???

yes, I should have said that I know my bug was about using <- instead of =, which brought this strange behavior to light.
